# How to use UpKeep Automation Payable function In Chainlink

Tags: automation, chainlink

I want to send native ETH to another smart contract address using a function. But when I try to send using payable(toaddress).send function or call value function it throws error. And say that I have to use use Payable function to send to another address.

`solidity

```
function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external payable override {
    //call
      (bool sent, ) = forgreenAdd.call{value: 10000000000}("");
}
```

`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLn7X.png)

I have tried with some functions with payable. All of them worked perfectly. But when I try to use payable for performUpkeep. It does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract that you should automate is the one that is going to send the money not the one that is going to receive, so think of that I create 2 possibilities that you could do:

Receiver.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Receiver {
    receive() external payable  { 
    }

    function giveMeMoney() external payable {
    }
}
```

Sender.sol (Automate this contract using Chainlink)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

interface IReceiver {
    function giveMeMoney() external payable;
}

contract Sender {
    address receiverAddress;
    IReceiver receiverContract;

    constructor(address _receiverAddress) {
        receiverAddress = _receiverAddress;
        receiverContract = IReceiver(_receiverAddress);
    }

    receive() external payable  { 
    }

    function sendEth(uint256 amount) public {
        if(address(this).balance > amount) {
            payable(receiverAddress).transfer(amount);
        }
    }

    function sendEthWithMethod(uint256 amount) public {
        receiverContract.giveMeMoney{value: amount}();
    }
}
```